# Rspec rails : check if object.value is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, type-conversion, boolean

I'm testing a **cron** job in rails and I want to test if an attribute of object to be false by default, this the portion of code that do the job :

```
describe ".perform()" do
    before :each do
      SendReportCronJob.perform()
    end

    context "automatically_send_report" do

      it "should be false by default" do
        binding.pry()
        expect( automatically_send_report.value ).to be "false"
      end
    end
    context "time_limit" do

      it "should not be nil" do
        expect( time_limit_for_sending_report.value ).to_not be_nil
      end
    end

  end
```

the problem is the ***automatically_send_report.value*** return a "false" value !

here the output of rails console when I do `binding.pry()` :

```
#<Setting:0x00000009990878> {
             :id => "69617295-4209-4092-80cf-5934d1cf7d38",
     :related_id => "cd830ace-933a-4230-ad54-bd94e63d5d7b",
            :key => "automatically_send_report",
          :value => "false",
      :data_type => "boolean",
    :is_archived => false,
  :updated_by_id => nil,
      :device_id => nil,
     :created_at => Wed, 18 Apr 2018 18:34:35 +03 +03:00,
     :updated_at => Wed, 18 Apr 2018 18:34:35 +03 +03:00
}
```

can I convert this value from string to boolean in the `rspec` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the string to boolean, you can compare strings as well, but in that case you need to use `eq` instead of `be`, as they are different objects with the same value:

```
expect(automatically_send_report.value).to eq "false"
```

Comment: Thanks  Anna Maria !